# Setting up Hot Key to zoom to Map Scale?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, scale, zoom

I'm wondering if I can set up a hot key to zoom to 1:4500 whenever I use it.

Also if I can set up a hot key to zoom in to 1:1250.

I have these two extents set up in the custom extent area and when I use my mouse scroll they come up but I want to be able to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> or something along those lines and then my map will zoom to 1:4500.

Is this possible or can you only set up the hot key to turn on zoom where you zoom in by drawing a box on the area?

Comment: If you are familiar with Add-Ins and developing them, you could develop a button that sets the map to your desired scale of 1:4500, and then set a hot-key to trigger that button. Then create another button that sets the scale to 1:1250, set a separate hot-key for that, and you're all set. The DataFrame object has a scale property that you can set: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/DataFrame/00s300000003000000/

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should investigate the suggestion of @DanJurgella:

> If you are familiar with Add-Ins and developing them, you could
>   develop a button that sets the map to your desired scale of 1:4500,
>   and then set a hot-key to trigger that button. Then create another
>   button that sets the scale to 1:1250, set a separate hot-key for that,
>   and you're all set. The DataFrame object has a scale property that you
>   can set:
>   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/DataFrame/00s300000003000000/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using bookmarks.

It would zoom to a specific extent at a specific location.  You would just have to enter the extent, save the bookmark, and click back to that bookmark whenever the user is choosing that extent.

Comment: Yeah I have 100's of bookmarks but that's just specific locations I go back to. The point of having these hot keys would be to use them on the fly and therefor have no reason to go back to the bookmarks.